# Loop thru a given folder path incrementally

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, for-loop

The script below prompt for folder path. Then the script shall loop thru the folder to create files.

For eg, input the path C:\aa. The script shall loop thru C:\aa\fol1 to C:\aa\fol5 to create files.

For eg, current folder C:\aa is empty.

```
Input C:\aa. 

Expected output would be 



C:\  -- aa -- fol1\aa1\bb1\cc1\dd1\00-1 with each subfolder has 20 files.
               -- fol2\aa2\bb2\cc2\dd2\00-2 with each subfolder has 20 files.
               -- fol3\aa3\bb3\cc3\dd3\00-3 with each subfolder has 20 files.
               -- fol4\aa4\bb4\cc4\dd4\00-4 with each subfolder has 20 files.
               -- fol5\aa5\bb5\cc5\dd5\00-5 with each subfolder has 20 files.
```

---

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set /p folder="Enter path: (C:\aa) : "
set /p action="Choose an action (Modify for M , Add for A , Delete for D , Rename for R , F for create Folder and files ): "

pause

2>NUL CALL :CASE_%action% # jump to :CASE_M, :CASE_A, etc.
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 CALL :DEFAULT_CASE # if label doesn't exist

ECHO Done.
EXIT /B

:CASE_F
  FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,5) DO (


    mkdir "%folder%"\fol"%%A"\aa"%%A"\bb"%%A"\cc"%%A"\dd"%%A"\00-"%%A"
  )

  timeout 11 > NUL

  FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,5) DO (


    mkdir "%folder%"\fol"%%A"\uu"%%A"\bb"%%A"\cc"%%A"\dd"%%A"\00-"%%A"
  )
  timeout 11 > NUL
  echo end of create folder
  pause

  FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,5) DO (
      echo %folder%\fol%%A
      set pfolderpath=%folder%\fol%%A
      pause

      for /D /r "%pfolderpath%" %%F in (*) do (
        echo LALA
        FOR /L %%B IN (1,1,20) DO (
        @echo this is new line > "%%F"\bear"%%B".txt
        )
      )
  )
  GOTO END_CASE

:END_CASE
  VER > NUL # reset ERRORLEVEL
  GOTO :EOF # return from CALL
```

The script above successfully create the subfolders fol1\aa1\bb1\cc1\dd1\00-1 to fol5. Just that it can't seem to loop into the fol1 to fol5 to create the files. The script works well if i hardcode pfolderpath with absolute path C:\aa\fol1. I guess its something wrong with the for loop but clueless. Please advice.

Comment: actually my script successfully create the subfolders, Just that it just won't go into  FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,5) DO (
      echo %folder%\fol%%A
      set pfolderpath=%folder%\fol%%A
      pause

      for /D /r "%pfolderpath%" %%F in (*) do (
        echo LALA
        FOR /L %%B IN (1,1,20) DO (
        @echo this is new line > "%%F"\bear"%%B".txt
        )
      )
  ) to create the files in the subfolders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following code section to have the two innermost loops run and the files created in the newly created folders:

```
  for /D /r "%pfolderpath%" %%F in (*) do (
    echo LALA
    FOR /L %%B IN (1,1,20) DO (
    @echo this is new line > "%%F"\bear"%%B".txt
    )
  )
```

to:

```
  PUSHD !pfolderpath!
  for /r %%F in (.) do (
    echo LALA
    FOR /L %%B IN (1,1,20) DO (
    @echo this is new line > "%%F"\bear"%%B".txt
    )
  )
  POPD
```

Note that there are 5 changes:

1. Use !pfolderpath! instead of %pfolderpath%, together with Delayed Expansion this will do what you want
2. Delete the double-quotes
3. Delete the /D
4. Enter the directory before the for /r. I'm using PUSHD paired with POPD here to ensure that after execution the script hasn't changed the path. Note that it should be possible to specify the !pfolderpath! root directory right in the for /r command as well.
5. Use `.` as the set to enumerate just the folders. You would use `*` if you wanted to enumerate files, but there aren't any yet.

Also note for anyone testing this script that you must respond `F` to the prompt "Choose an action"; the others aren't implemented here.

Comment: i have tried with the code. The code did loop into the for-loop. However, seem to failed to create files. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: The script create files at the location where the script is executed. It didn't create the files at intended location.

Comment: Just made an edit to fix the problem with the file location too.